# Joint pdf given points on square

Tags: probability, density-function

I'm unsure of how to find the joint PDF of something like this

Assume that X1, X2 is uniform on the square with corners
(-1,0), (0, —1), (0, l), (1,0)

I know that it is double integration with bounds [-1, 1] for x and [-1, 1] for y. However, what am I integrating?

Comment: The square area is $\,\sqrt{\, 2\,}\,\,\sqrt{\, 2\,}\, = \color{red}{2}$.

Comment: Where did you get the square root? I'm assuming it's 2 underneath the square root because that's the difference between the largest and smallest x/y? Also, in my book's example they're using (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1,1) and have the joint pdf as 1/4

Comment: You are integrating over the square.  For $(-1,0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1,0)$ it might be inconvenient to write out the integral limits, but the (tilted) square is what you are integrating over.  Also, the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from inspection - just draw the square and you will see.

Comment: Ok, I see where the sqrt(2) is coming into play. Looks like that is the hypotenuse of the triangle using a = 1 and b = 1. So, for these kind of problems, all I'm basically doing is finding the area of the shape? If this is the case, why does the example in my book have the joint pdf as 1/4 instead of 4?

Answer (score 0):

The joint density is given by $f(x,y)=\frac 1 4$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1,-1 \leq x \leq 1$ (0 elsewhere). The distribution function is $F(x,y)=\frac 1 4 \int_{-1}^{x} \int_{-1}^{y} d xdy=\frac 1 4 (x+1)(y+1)$ for $x,y \in [-1,1]$. It is $\frac 1 4 \int_{-1}^{x} \int_{-1}^{1} d xdy=\frac 1 2 (x+1)$ for $x \in [-1,1], y>1$ etc.